# Help doing an exercise on a criterion for affiness from Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, affine-schemes

So far I have managed to do all the exercises in section 2 of chapter 2 of Hartshorne's algebraic geometry except for question 2.16c. In fact, I have even looked at solutions to it and am unable to follow them, so I really don't know where to begin with giving an attempt. The setup of the question is as follows:

Let $X$ be a scheme and let $f \in \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_{X})$ be a global section. Define $X_{f}$ to be the set of points of $x \in X$ such that the stalk $f_{x}$ of $f$ is not contained in the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_{x}$ of the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X, x}$.

Part (a) asks: If $U = \text{Spec} B$ is an open affine subscheme of $X$ and if $\tilde{f} \in B = \Gamma(U, \mathcal{O}_{X}|_{U})$ is the restriction of $f$ to $U$, then show that $U \cap X_{f} = D(\tilde{f})$. Conclude that $X_{f}$ is an open subset of $X$.

Part (b) asks: Assume that $X$ is quasi-compact. Let $A = \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_{X})$ and let $a \in A$ be an element whose restriction to $X_{f}$ is $0$. Show that for some $n>0$, $f^{n}a = 0$.

Part (c) asks: Now assume that $X$ has a finite cover by open affines $\{ U_{i} \}$ such that each intersection $U_{i} \cap U_{j}$ is quasi-compact. Let $b \in \Gamma(X_{f}, \mathcal{O}_{X_{f}})$. Show that for some $n > 0$, $f^{n}b$ is the restriction of an element of $A$.

I know that we need to use the fact that the intersections of open affines are quasi-compact and apply part (b), but I haven't been able to actually do this. There are three solutions online that I have been looking at but they haven't been particularly helpful, the best one being [here](http://math.arizona.edu/~cais/CourseNotes/AlgGeom04/Hartshorne_Solutions.pdf).

Is someone able to give me some more details as to how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Your post seems to be a bit incomplete - none of the solutions you mention linking to are displayed.

Comment: At the very least, you should state what the problem is!

Comment: Not everyone has a copy of Hartshorne, and not everyone who has one has their copy available. A question should be self-contained whenever possible, never depending on outside sources, online or offline, for it to be understood. Using and referencing outside sources is fine, depending on them and requiring them is not.

Comment: @KReiser I've fixed the link (the URL was in the post, but the Markdown needed fixing).

Comment: @TakumiMurayama, thanks for fixing that up. I've improved on the question and given my own solution below. Do you think you'd be able to see if there's any glaring errors if you get a chance?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, sorry, I was quite rushed when I wrote this. I've fixed things up to a better standard now. If you get a chance, do you think you could glance at the answer below and see if it seems correct?

Comment: @Arthur, point taken. I've fixed up the question and offered my own potential answer after thinking about this some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize for the poorly worded question, I admit I was a bit rushed. I'd like to post my own answer though now that I have finally figured it out as well as fix up the question. I thought this might be useful since I found it very insightful and the solutions online seem to be lacking a lot of detail.

Suppose we have a finite cover $\{ U_{i} = \text{Spec} B_{i}  \}$ for $X$. This then provides an affine (by part a) cover $\{ X_{f} \cap \text{Spec} B_{i} \}$ for $X_{f}$. Let $b \in \Gamma(X_{f}, \mathcal{O}_{X_{f}})$. Denote the restriction of $f$ to $U_{i}$ by $f_{i}$. Since, by part (a), $U_{i} \cap X_{f} = D(f_{i})$, for each $i$ we have
$$
b|_{X_{f} \cap U_{i}} = \frac{b_{i}}{f_{i}^{d_{i}}} \quad \text{with } b_{i} \in B_{i} .
$$
Denote the restriction of $f_{i}$ to $ U_{i} \cap U_{j}$ by $f_{ij}$. Then we may write
$$
b_{i}|_{X_{f} \cap U_{i} \cap U_{j}} = f_{ij}^{d_{i}} \left(  b|_{X_{f} \cap U_{i} \cap U_{j}}  \right).
$$
Note that we have abused notation slightly: By $f_{ij}^{d_{i}}$, we mean the restriction of this to $U_{i} \cap U_{j} \cap X_{f}$. Then there holds
$$
f_{ij}^{d_{j}}b_{i}|_{X_{f} \cap U_{i} \cap U_{j}} - f_{ij}^{d_{i}}b_{j}|_{X_{f} \cap U_{i} \cap U_{j}} = \left( f_{ij}^{d_{i}+d_{j}} - f_{ij}^{d_{j}+d_{i}} \right) \left(  b|_{X_{f} \cap U_{i} \cap U_{j}}  \right) = 0.
$$
But the above section is precisely the restriction of the section 
$$
a_{ij}:=f_{ij}^{d_{j}+d_{i}} b_{i}|_{U_{i} \cap U_{j}} - f_{ij}^{d_{i}+d_{j}}b_{j}|_{U_{j} \cap U_{j}}.
$$
So by part (b) of the question, since $U_{i \cap U_{j}}$ is quasi-compact, there is some integer $N_{ij}$ such that $f_{ij}^{N_{ij}}a_{ij} = 0$. Since there are only finitely many of the $U_{i}$, we can choose the largest such $N_{ij}$ which we will call $M$. Then for any intersection $U_{i} \cap U_{j}$ of affine open sets in the cover, there holds
$$
f^{M}a_{ij} = f_{ij}^{d_{j}+d_{i}+M} b_{i}|_{U_{i} \cap U_{j}} - f_{ij}^{d_{i}+ d_{j}+M} b_{j}|_{U_{i} \cap U_{j}} = 0.
$$
This is still dependent on the $i, j$. However, since there are only finitely many of these, we can define
$$
d:= \sum_{i} d_{i}
$$
so that for any intersection $U_{i} \cap U_{j}$ of affine open sets in the cover, there holds,
$$
f^{M}a_{ij} = f_{ij}^{d+M} b_{i}|_{U_{i} \cap U_{j}} - f_{ij}^{d+M} b_{j}|_{U_{i} \cap U_{j}} = 0.
$$
In other words, on the intersection $U_{i} \cap U_{j}$, we have the agreement
$$
f_{ij}^{d+M} b_{i}|_{U_{i} \cap U_{j}} = f_{ij}^{d+M} b_{j}|_{U_{i} \cap U_{j}}.
$$
By the gluing property for sheaves, this allows us to glue across the affine cover such that
$$
f^{M+d}b = 0,
$$
which completes the proof.

Comment: This looks correct to me, except for one small thing: in the third to last equation, the equation should probably be $$f^{M+d}a_{ij} = f_{ij}^{d+M+d_j+d_i}b_i\rvert_{U_i \cap U_j} - f_{ij}^{d+M+d_i+d_j}b_j\rvert_{U_i \cap U_j} = 0$$ to match the preceding equation.